# Javascript prop('required', true) works but prop('required', false) doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the $('#select_embed') property get set to true, but not to false?  Instead, I tried removeAttribute('required'), but that didn't work either.

```
<script>

    function showBundles(){
        if (document.getElementById("embed").checked){
            $('#div_embed_bundles').show('fast')
            $('#select_embed').prop('required',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#div_embed_bundles').hide('fast')
            $('#select_embed').prop('required',false);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White: In HTML5, form fields can have the `required` property set, to indicate that the field is required.

Comment: @MFB: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pxqFD/1/

Comment: `if ( $('#embed')[0].checked ) { ...` No need for `getElementsById`

Comment: @Daniel A. White, thank you, that is indeed why I'm setting and unsetting it.

Comment: @Joseph Silber, Thank you, your fiddle even works when I change the control to a select, however, it still doesn't work on my form :-(  I am using the Google javascript, maybe there is a difference (bug).

Comment: @Sime Vidas:  Thank you... that's a good one.

Comment: @MFB: What is "the Google javascript"?

Comment: To see if it is checked:`$('#embed').is(':checked')`

Comment: @Joseph Sibler: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ideally if `prop('required',true)` is working then `prop('required',false)` should also work. But you can try with `removeAttr`, hope this helps.

```
function showBundles(){
        if (document.getElementById("embed").checked){
            $('#div_embed_bundles').show('fast')
            $('#select_embed').prop('required',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#div_embed_bundles').hide('fast')
            $('#select_embed').removeAttr('required');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @ShankarSangoli.  I had ended up using removeAttr('required').  It was the only method that worked.

Comment: Can confirm `removeAttr()` works in my case and `.prop()` set to false doess not.

Answer (score 4):

Use attr() instead of prop().
I used attr('required', true) and attr('required',false) and both worked perfectly.
Read the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/attr/ to know when to use attr() and when to use prop()

Or read the essential parts of the documentation on .attr() below:

.attr():
Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Attributes vs. Properties
The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Comment: Could you include the link's content in your answer? This is helpful because after a while, this link could be subject to link rot, or the website itself could go down.

Comment: @TheMaker, I've edited my answer to include link's content. Check it out.